# How do we know if a Killing Spinor is Time-like or Null?

Tags: supersymmetry, spinors, vector-fields, supergravity

How to know whether a Killing spinor orbit is time-like or null? This is present in a paper like this 29/39 [here.](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/research/hep/conferences/branes/pkt_talks/papadopoulos.pdf) I'm not asking for a technical answer, just a logical cliche answer chit-chat answer.

Let me go into more details here

> The KSEs for $N = 1$ backgrounds have been solved using spinor bilinears. In the spinorial approach [Gillard, Gran, GP], the KSEs are solved utilizing the representatives of the two orbits.
>   $\epsilon = f(1+e_{12345})$: Solutions admit a **time-like** Killing vector field and its orbit space has a SU(5) structure.
>
> $\epsilon = 1+e_{1234}$: Solutions admit a **null** Killing vector field, the
>   spacetime has a $Spin(7)\times \mathbb{R}^9$ structure and include backgrounds like
>   pp-wave propagating in a $Spin(7)$ manifold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see whether a Killing spinor is timelike or null, you need to make a following combination.
$$
V_\mu\epsilon^{ab}=\bar{\epsilon}^a\gamma_\mu\epsilon^b\,.
$$
Then using Fierz identities, you can compute the norm of the vector $V_\mu$, and see whether it is timelike or null. For example, in five-dimensional minimal supergravity, you will find that 
$$
V_\mu V^\mu=f^2\,,
$$
where $f$ is a scalar which is also constructed by using a Killing spinor $\epsilon^a$ such as
$$
f\epsilon^{ab}=\bar\epsilon^a\epsilon^b\,.
$$

I first met this concepts of a timelike or null Killing spinor in [hep-th/0209114](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0209114).